# We need to improve our [communication]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication) tag is merely described as

> Communication is the activity of conveying information.

That's not even a programming concept.

Looking through the questions shows that there's absolutely no consistency in how the tag is used.

Can we remove this tag?

Comment: That's a lot of questions to filter through.  Have you taken example from your earlier burnination requests and put together some kind of angle of attack for us to start on?  Simply saying "go" isn't really enough.  Do you personally think the tag is worth keeping around, and if you don't, what should we do with all the questions that are tagged it?  Just *removing* it would create a colossal mess since really bad questions would just disappear elsewise.

Comment: There's some mis[communication] here

Comment: Seems like [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51624/5894241) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1724381/5894241) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321546/5894241) [high-voted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1680898/5894241) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231764/5894241) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169765/5894241) [close-worthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310282/5894241) [as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278199/5894241).

Comment: I like how a single comment closed 8 questions within 20 hours

Comment: This one's my favorite of the questions that only have this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822062/does-there-exist-a-communication-tool-thatd-be-better-suited-for-programming-re

Comment: @Roddyofthefrozenpeas that might have the shorted accepted answer ever.

Comment: @Luuklag actually your search wasn't perfect, even on the first page of results, there are questions with several other tags besides [communication]

Comment: Maybe modify the description - Communication is an activity associated with conveying ideas, opinions, information and also helps in establishing context, while imparting knowledge!!!

Comment: @user2347763 - Modifying the description won't help with the fact that the majority of the questions using this tag are blatantly off-topic.

Comment: Modifying the description to clearly define 'communication' for what a community agrees to, by consensus, should anyway be a given, whether it helps or not is secondary.

Primarily, the concern is to ensure that the description has not left any room for ambiguity because as is, it sounds like it describes the activity of passing information as 'communication', that fits a description of a kind of a media or a 'spy' activity.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you are right. Removed my comment. Makes me wonder if there is a propper way of doing this...