# What should be done to the [spm] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

Recently, I stumbled upon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64893025/8697793) tagged with [swift-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-package-manager) *and* [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm).

Tag descriptions:

- [swift-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-package-manager) (461 questions)

> Swift Package Manager is a build tool and dependency manager for
> projects written in Swift. It is made by Apple and is open source.

- [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) (41 questions)

> SPM (Statistical Parametric Mapping) is a matlab library for
> preprocessing and analysis of functional Magnetic Resonance Imaging
> (fMRI) data.

However, if we take a look at [questions tagged [spm]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) we can see that around half of these questions are related to Swift Package Manager (mostly the newest ones).

If most of the new questions tagged [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) are in fact related to Swift Package Manager, what should be done with this tag?

One idea is that questions related to `Statistical Parametric Mapping` can be retagged as [matlab-spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-spm) and then, [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) can be synonymised with [swift-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-package-manager).

What is the best solution here?

Comment: I think `spm` should just be renamed `matlab-spm`. I don't see a reason to make it a synonym for swift when the actual MATLAB library is specifically called SPM... After the rename people will probably not use it for swift related stuff. And there are only about 20 questions to retag which is not so much...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks, this makes sense. But someone will surely add more questions with the `spm` tag. If so, what the `spm` description should be?

Comment: Sorry for the "noob" question, but if someone just "invents" something in the tags, does that create it as a new tag? If so, than in that case I still think it would make more sense to make `spm` a synonym of `matlab-spm`. This way when someone tags swift with `spm` it would "pop" more that it's out of place (assuming it will magically become `matlab-spm`)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo *"if someone just "invents" something in the tags, does that create it as a new tag?"* - I believe so, but I'm not 100% sure. And I agree that synonymising `spm` with `matlab-spm` should work.

Comment: Those questions tagged with the [tag:spm] tag that are about Swift Package Manager should be retagged with [tag:swift-package-manager].  Since there are at most 40 questions (actually, quite a lot less) to deal with, those with sufficient power (reputation) to edit without bothering the review queues can do the job easily.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The residual problem is people misusing the [tag:spm] tag.  It can't be all that active.  I monitor the [tag:ar] tag, getting email when new questions arrive.  I retag those questions that are about augmented reality (the majority of the incoming questions) with the right tag — or at least remove the wrong tag.  Someone, preferably with an interest in MatLab SPM, could monitor incoming messages to the [tag:spm] tag and deal with the erroneously tagged messages.

Comment: In fact, there are no longer any questions about Swift Package Manager that are mistagged with the [tag:spm] tag.  The residual problem is as mentioned before: spotting the misuse (abuse?) of the [tag:spm] tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot - so, after retagging swift-related questions to `swift-package-manager`, the `spm` tag can probably be renamed to `matlab-spm` to prevent (at least try) the tag misuse. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not going to take a strong view on renaming the [tag:spm] tag.  I would leave it alone; it has been around longer than the Swift Package Manager has been around and takes precedence because of that.  I've signed up to watch the tag — it'll be at most a few questions per week to retag.  I'd prefer it if someone else did the watching, but as long as the watching is done, it doesn't matter much who does it.  It's pretty easy for even a rank outsider (someone who wasn't aware of the existence of either the [tag:spm] or [tag:swift-package-manager] tags before seeing this question) to retag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, makes sense. Thanks for the help ;) I'm already watching the `swift` tag, so now that I'm aware of the existence of the `spm` tag, I'll be retagging these questions (if I see them).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

Those questions tagged with the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag that are about Swift Package Manager are mistagged and should simply be retagged with the [swift-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-package-manager) tag. Since there are at most 40 questions (actually, quite a lot less) to deal with, those with sufficient power (reputation) to edit without bothering the review queues can do the job easily.

The residual problem is people misusing the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag. It can't be all that active. I monitor the [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) tag, getting email when new questions arrive. I retag those questions that are about augmented reality (the majority of the incoming questions) with the right tag — or at least remove the wrong tag. Someone, preferably with an interest in MatLab SPM, could monitor incoming messages to the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag and deal with the erroneously tagged messages.

*[…time passeth…]* In fact, there are no longer any questions about Swift Package Manager that are mistagged with the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag. The residual problem is as mentioned before: spotting the misuse (abuse?) of the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag.

> Thanks a lot.  So, after retagging swift-related questions to [swift-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-package-manager), the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag can probably be renamed to [matlab-spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-spm) to prevent (at least try) the tag misuse. Is this correct?

I'm not going to take a strong view on renaming the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag. I would leave it alone; it has been around longer than the Swift Package Manager has been around and takes precedence because of that, but I have no involvement with either tag on a routine basis so there could be compelling reasons to take a different viewpoint and I probably wouldn't have any quibbles about that.

I note that you need 1500 reputation points before you can create tags.  Novices on the site are most likely to misuse tags.  Renaming the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag would prevent it being recreated by people with too little reputation.  But I am not convinced it is necessary.

I've signed up to watch the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) tag (on the wiki information page) — it'll be at most a few questions per week to retag. I'd prefer it if someone else did the watching, but as long as the watching is done, it doesn't matter much who does it. It's pretty easy for even a rank outsider (someone who wasn't aware of the existence of either the [spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spm) or [swift-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-package-manager) tags before seeing this question) to retag.

Comment: Or... a moderator can rename the tag. The tag is now [matlab-spm] with [spm] as a synonym. Just FYI, acronym tags are usually problematic because they can have more than one meaning. Speaking from experience, people will continue to assign whatever meaning they want to an acronym and renames are the only way to stop them.

Comment: That works too, @Machavity.  Thank you for deciding on the rename.  I'll stop watching the tag since there's not much chance of someone using the renamed tag for Swift Package Manager, so there shouldn't be a need for me to intervene.

Comment: Your second to last paragraph really puts the nail in the coffin regarding my first comment on the question. Assuming most mis-use will happen with new/low-rep users, renaming the tag with a `matlab` prefix will prevent it from being used with swift (hopefully people are not ***that*** careless) and what you brought up assures it will not simply get re-created as `spm` on swift questions...

Answer (score 6):

I renamed the tag (per [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402960/what-should-be-done-to-the-spm-tag#comment808896_402960)) to [matlab-spm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-spm). Acronym tags are often assigned whatever meaning suits the poster, and the excerpt is often ignored. A tag rename tends to fix this for good.

Comment: Thanks Machavity, hopefully this should solve the *spm* problem for good.

Comment: Apparently we've underestimated the carelessness of folks, as I just re-tagged a dozen new Swift-related posts that were tagged with `matlab-spm`, sigh. Would it be worth creating an empty `swift-spm` tag (or similar) just to add it as a synonym, so that `swift-package-manager` shows up when folks type `spm` in the tag box? I imagine right now folks type `spm`, don't see swift anywhere in the options, and pick the closest thing that shows up.

Comment: @cincodenada Sounds like a good idea. [swift-spm] is now a synonym

Comment: Just confirmed, and `[swift-package-manager]` now shows up second as a suggestion for `spm`, looks great. Thanks! Hopefully that will nudge folks in the right direction :)