# Return randomness to the selection of Hot Meta Posts

Tags: feature-request, meta, community-bulletin

I've noticed that the Hot Meta Posts don't get rotation anymore. This causes some topics to dominate the list and doesn't allow for other topics to get any chance of visibility. There was a change back in the day where the [list was updated each 20 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467/792066), which gave topics enough rotation to make sure that the list doesn't go stale.

Can we have randomness/rotation again on the Hot Meta Posts?

Comment: [And how do you know they aren't actually random?](https://www.random.org/analysis/dilbert.jpg)

Comment: @yivi the fact that the 4 post featured [match this list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20score%3a3%20created%3a3d..) :D Also, that probably they made SO follow the same rules as other sites.

Comment: @yivi nah, the response was more in case someone wanted some evidence, see smiley :D